# Haskell Program for Levenshtein distance

Tags: haskell, levenshtein-distance

I need a program in Haskell that computes the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: This is not even a question

Answer (score 5):

You need to calculate the Levenshtein distance (also called the edit distance) which is defined as follow for strings `a` and `b`: (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)):

[image]

Because the values of lev(i,j) only depends on previous values, we can take advantage of Haskell's lazyness to intialize an Array where the value of element at position (i, j) is a function of previous values of the same array! See [Dynamic programming example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Dynamic_programming_example) to see examples of how this can be done.

Here goes an basic implementation for `lev`:

```
import Data.Array

lev :: String -> String -> Int
lev x y = c ! (m, n)
  where
    c = listArray ((0, 0), (m, n)) [compute i j | i <- [0 .. m], j <- [0 .. n]]
    compute 0 j = j
    compute i 0 = i
    compute i j
      | x !! (i - 1) == y !! (j - 1) = c ! (i - 1, j - 1)
      | otherwise = 1 + (minimum $ map (c !) [(i , j - 1),
                                              (i - 1, j),
                                              (i - 1, j - 1)])
    m = length x
    n = length y
```

This code can be further optimized, but should give you a good idea to get started.

After computing the Levenshtein, you just need to compare it with the edit cost bound k.

Comment: @user3041551 Ah sorry, what you really needed is the Levenshtein distance and not the LCS. I always mix up the two of them, my bad. I've edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Pedro Rodrigues, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3041551 You're welcome. If my answer helped, you might consider marking it as correct.